# Laravel Relationship Between Tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relational-database

I have generate the following database table and need to create model form them.

[image: Er Diagram]

Creating a model seems to be an easy task, but I am confused how should i define the relationship between two tables. In `users` table `RoleId` is foreign key. My question is where and how should I define the relationship (in User model or Role model). Should I use `hasOne`, `hasMany`, or `belongsTo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Role', 'id', 'RoleId');
}
```

In your Role model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'RoleId', 'id);
}
```

Comment: do i need to use both?

Comment: No you don't. The only reason you might want to add the `users()` function to your `Role` model is so that you can see what users have a specific role.

Comment: thanks. One more thing that confuses me is, one user can have only one role but you are using hasMany, is there any explanation for that or is my ER-Diagram wrong?

Comment: I corrected my answer. I did write the wrong function in there, should have been hasOne.

Comment: @rishal A hasOne in User and belongsTo in Role is a sign of a one-to-one relationship, but your ER diagram seems to indicate a one-to-many relationship (a USER associates to ONE ROLE, a ROLE associates to MANY USER). My guess is that you want to say that a user has one role. To do that, you can simply have a hasOne in User and nothing in Role.